# Not able to get attributes value while calling from init

Tags: python, list, function, class, init

In `__init__` method when i try to access `get_movie_detail` it displays an error that the object has no attribute.This happens when i try to get data from a list. When i tried returning a single variable in `get_movie_detail` eg. `return title`, it successfully returned the title but the same if i am trying to do with a list the below error appears:

Stack trace:

```
674
Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
7.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\movie trailer\entertainment.py", line 4, in <module>
    movie_name_1=media.Data('Harry potter and goblet of fire')
  File "C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\movie trailer\media.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.title = detail_new.detail_list[0] 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'detail_list'
```

Below is my code:

```
""" stores requested movie data"""
import webbrowser
import urllib.request
import json
import tmdbsimple as tmdb
tmdb.API_KEY = ''

class Data():

    """takes argument movie_name,searches the data from tmdb database
       tmdbSimple is wrapper&classes of tmdb
       movie name keyword should be precise so that api can fetch data
       accurately.Incomplete keyword could lead to unwanted results.

       Attributes:
           Search():search method in tmdbsimple.
           movie:movie method takes query and return results
           search_result:getd the result of searched movies includes
                         data regarding movies in list format.
           movie_id:stores the unique movie ID for a particular movie
           title:stores title of movie.
           imdb_rating:rating of movie.
           movie_overview:short description of movie.
           release_date:date on which movie released.
           data_yt:searches the movie keyword on youtube api for trailer.
           youtube_key:gets key from the search result in json format
           trailer.youtube_url:complete youtube link to the trailer
           poster_image_url:link to the poster of movie."""

    def get_movie_detail(self,movie_name):
        print("in am in get_movie_detail")
        #search movie id related to query from tmdb api
        search = tmdb.Search()
        response_old = search.movie(query=movie_name)
        search_result = search.results
        s_find = search_result[0]#gets the first id of the search result
        movie_id = s_find['id']
        print(movie_id)
        #uses movie id to get the details of movie
        movie = tmdb.Movies(movie_id)
        response = movie.info()#stores the movie information in dict format
        title = response['title']#if you try to print title in the definition it will print correctly
        print(title)
        vote = response['vote_average']
        print(vote)
        discript = response['overview']
        date = response['release_date']
        poster_id = response['poster_path']
        detail_list = [title,vote,discript,date,poster_id]
        return detail_list


        """" issue is that if i try calling from  __init__ its not returning any attributes of get_movie_detail,Is there scope issue?"""


    def get_trailer_link(self,movie_name):
        print("I am in get_trailer")
        query_new = urllib.parse.quote_plus(movie_name+'trailer')
        data_yt = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q="+query_new+"&type=video&key=")
        trailer_data = data_yt.read()
        youtube_json = json.loads(trailer_data)
        youtube_key = str(youtube_json['items'][0]['id']['videoId'])


    def __init__(self,movie_name):
      """stores the atrributes of instances"""
      detail_new = self.get_movie_detail(movie_name)
      self.title = detail_new.detail_list[0] #***while trying to get data from method it shows error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'***
      print(self.title)
      self.imdb_rating = detail_new.vote.detail_list[1]
      print(self.imdb_rating)
      self.movie_overview = detail_new.detail_list[2]
      print(self.movie_overview)
      self.release_date = detail_new.detail_list[3]
      print(self.release_date)
      #uses youtube api to get the url from the search result       
      #gets movie image from the database tmdbsimple api      
      self.trailer_youtube_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+str(self.get_trailer_link.youtube_key)

      self.poster_image_url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+str(poster_id)



    def trailer(self):
        """opens youtube url"""
        webbrowser.open(self.trailer_youtube_url)
```

Comment: Please post the actual stack trace.... it tells us exactly where the error is. Also, a good debug practice for python is to cut most of the clutter out in a test script to narrow down the problem. And that simplified example would be a good thing to post here.

Comment: What do you mean by "not returning any attributes"? What _does_ it return? What happens if you `print(detail_new)`? What if you `print(detail_list)` inside the method?

Comment: Also, since the method doesn't seem to be using `self` at all: what happens if you pull it out to a standalone function and then call it from top-level code, like `print(get_movie_detail(<whatever>))`?

Comment: when i print the detail_list inside a method it properly prints the data.but when i try to call from init function it return  . . 'list' object has no attribute 'detail_list'

Comment: i tried putting that function get_movie_detail  outside the class and tried calling it but still it returns same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to try to access `detail_list`, your `detail_new` is that list.

You can get the title by accessing `detail_new[0]`.

So that portion of your `__init__()` function becomes:

```
self.title = detail_new[0]
self.imdb_rating = detail_new[1]
self.movie_overview = detail_new[2]
self.release_date = detail_new[3]
```